# Why indexOnly attribute is false for this covered query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a test db with fields _id, name, age, date

Indexes:

```
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "blogger.users"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "name" : 1,
                    "age" : 1
            },
            "name" : "name_1_age_1",
            "ns" : "blogger.users"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "age" : 1,
                    "name" : 1
            },
            "name" : "age_1_name_1",
            "ns" : "blogger.users"
    }
]
```

When running the following query:

```
> db.users.find({"name":"user10"},{"_id":0,"date":0})
     .explain()
```

I get following:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "name" : [
                    [
                            "user10",
                            "user10"
                    ]
            ],
            "age" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "Johny-PC:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
```

}

Without explain the result is:

```
{ "name" : "user10", "age" : 68 }
```

Even though this is a covered query with proper projections, the `indexOnly` field is still false. I have also tried explicitly providing index using hint, but no change. In that case values of `nscannedObjectsAllPlans` and `nscannedAllPlans` are 1 as the query doesnt try other indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a query to be "indexOnly" or "covered" the only fields returned must be contained in the index. So even though you have an index for "name_1_age_1", the query engine still expects to be "told" that the only fields you want are those in the index. It does not know this about the document until you inspect it:

```js
db.users.find({"name":"user10"},{"_id":0, "name": 1, "age": 1 }).explain()
```

That will return "indexOnly" as the query engine knows that the selected index contains all of the fields that are required for output. As such there is no need to go back through the collection in case there are other fields to return.

Comment: Also, I have added the projection for _id:0. I guess that is enough?

Comment: @johny No it will not. You can always "exclude" `_id` but you cannot mix and match other fields. That means you can explictly include or exclude. Not both. So `_id` is the only exception here

Comment: The reality is I actually excluded one field(date) from question, which I thought was irrelevant. So, if I have to exclude that key too this error shows up.

Comment: @johny The answer explains that just excluding `_id` is not enough quite clearly. MongoDB is schemaless. The query optimizer cannot possibly tell that all documents only contain the fields in the selected index. That is why you tell it which fields you want. `_id` is not present in the index so you exclude that and include the fields only that are present. Honestly would have been much simpler for you if you just ran the statement.